# Problem regarding a homomorphic mapping

Tags: abstract-algebra

I can't understand this:

suppose we have a homomorphism $\phi :G \to G'$  such that it induces these two maps :

$$\phi_*:\tau\to \tau'$$ ,a map from subgroups of G to subgroups of G'

s.t $\phi_*(H)=\phi(H)$
 and similarly,$$\phi^*:\tau'\to \tau$$  ,a map from subgroups of G' to subgroups of G.
s.t $\phi^*(H)=\phi^{-1}(H)$

If these two maps aren't inverses of each other:
What I can't understand is this.  we've
 $$\phi_*\phi^*(H')=H'\cap im\phi$$
$$\phi^*\phi_*(H)=\langle H,Ker \phi \rangle$$ i.e smallest subgroup containing $H$ and $Ker \phi$

kindly help me with this.

Comment: It can only do good to your question (and eagerness to answer) to mention explicitly what is meant by $\tau$ and $\tau '$

Comment: @drhab I've edited what do $\tau$ and $\tau'$ represent..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y\in\phi_{*}\left(\phi^{*}\left(H\right)\right)\iff y=\phi\left(x\right)\text{ for some }x\in\phi^{*}\left(H\right)\iff $$$$y=\phi\left(x\right)\text{ for some }x\in G\text{ with }\phi\left(x\right)\in H\iff y\in H\wedge y\in\operatorname{im}\phi$$

and:

$$x\in\phi^{*}\left(\phi*\left(H'\right)\right)\iff\phi\left(x\right)\in\phi_{*}\left(H'\right)\iff$$$$\phi\left(x\right)=\phi\left(a\right)\text{ for some }a\in H'\iff x-a\in\text{ker}\phi\text{ for some }a\in H'\iff$$$$ x=a+b\text{ for some }a\in H'\text{ and some }b\in\operatorname{ker}\phi$$

Comment: thanks a lot for explanation....

Comment: you are very welcome.